# git merge origin master "Already up-to-date"

Tags: git, merge

New to git. Using git enterprise on a Mac.

So I have been working in a branch in IntelliJ IDEA, let's call it "foo".  So master->foo.

Was happy with my changes, so I pushed/committed them to the remote repo.  At that point I was ready to start the process to merge the changes into master.  But first, I wanted to merge any changes from master into my branch and test them.

So, with "foo" still checked out, I ran "git merge origin/master".

This brought in the changes I was expecting.  I resolved any conflicts.  At this point I found something I wanted to modify before doing the merge.  So in IntelliJ, I went to the "Version Control" window under the "Local Changes" tab.  Right-clicked and selected "Revert".

This reverted the merge as expected.  I made my changes and ran "git merge origin/master" again.  But now it says "Already up-to-date".

Help!

Comment: Is there a reason you wanted to "revert" the merge? You could just as easily make your changes and commit it on top of the merge.

Answer (score 3):

A merge consists of two parts - changing the files in the current snapshot, and making a commit with 2 parents that tells git the merge has been done. When you do a `git revert` on a merge commit, it undoes the former, but not the latter. So as far as git is concerned, you have already merged in `origin/master`. The only way to "re merge" after reverting a merge commit is to call `git revert` again, passing it the commit that the previous `git revert` generated; you have to "revert the revert".

Comment: Does `git revert` create a new commit which "undoes" the changes?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - yes, `git revert` always creates a new commit.

Comment: Of course there is an underlying assumption here that the "Revert" command in the IntelliJ IDE translates to `git revert`. From my experience this kind of translation between a GUI menu item and the command line is sometimes not so literal. In particular, the "Revert" command in Android Studio is equivalent to `git reset --hard HEAD` from what I have seen. This may differ in IntelliJ, though.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you start a branch on the merge commit and make your changes there. Then you can make a new commit with the changes. I don't see any reason for "reverting".

If you really want to undo the merge before making the changes, you need to use `git reset` from the command line or "Reset to hear..." in the Version Control window of IntelliJ IDEA. Then you can make your changes, but you will also have to do the merge again along with resolving conflicts. This seems like much more work than it is worth.

Comment: `git reset` will only revert changes made if they've already been committed - if he had to do conflict resolution, this will not have happened automatically. `git reset`, when performed without the --hard option, only unstages changes that are to be committed, meaning he will not need to do the merge again if he has not committed https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

Comment: @EddiePrislac Right...I forgot to include the difference between `--hard` and `--soft` and the rest. I almost always use `--hard` so I often forget the other options are available.